# Why can't I see my GPU in blender

Tags: gpu

I can't see my GPU in the user preferences. It shows *none* and no name of GPU is selectable. In the system device manager list I can see my GPU. I'm using blender 2.79.

**My system**

[image]

**Device Manager**

[image]

Comment: Do you have the [CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/) drivers installed? Also, your GPU is probably supported, but it doesn't hurt to check: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#cuda.